# Is it harmful to keep PC always on?

Tags: windows-xp, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to leave your computer on all the time?](https://superuser.com/questions/2733/is-it-better-to-leave-your-computer-on-all-the-time)

i always keep PC on . just switch off monitor when i don't use.

Is it harmful for PC hardwares and softwares?

i use Windows XP as a OS on one PC and MAC osx leopard on another PC and i keep on both of them. because i keey multiple programs and tabs in firefox most of the time and in night i keep downloading in process so i don't shutdown the PC and MAC.

Comment: @Ivo - should i delete my this question?

Comment: no need to, it was closed as a duplicate, and is useful to keep, for example to provide another way of phrasing the question, that can be found by search engines.